# MyBatis enum type handler only works for either reads or writes, not both

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, typehandler

I have a spring boot project using mybatis 3.5.9 and I'm trying to add a custom type handler for an enum that looks like

```
public enum Foo {
  VALUE_A("A"),
  VALUE_B("B");

  String value;
  //getters and such...
}
```

I added `mybatis.type-handlers-package` to application properties

The handler is a pretty standard

```
@MappedTypes(Foo.class)
public class FooHandler implements TypeHandler<Foo> {
//the usual setParameter and getResult overrides
}
```

When reading data this works fine, I can put a breakpoint in the handler and I see that it's being used and I get my enum. When writing, however, the type handler isn't being used, mybatis is trying to write the full "VALUE_A" to the DB column.

On the other hand, if I annotate it with the mapped JDBC type like

```
@MappedTypes(Foo.class)
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR)
public class FooHandler implements TypeHandler<Foo> {
//the usual setParameter and getResult overrides
}
```

Then writing works fine but reading doesn't.
I can solve the problem by getting rid of the jdbc type annotation and sticking an explicit `typeHandler=com.example.FooHandler}` into every SQL statement, but I have a lot of mappers and really this should just work globally, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I ran into a MyBatis bug, where enums don't play nice if they override some method, like so

```
public enum Foo {
  VALUE_A("A"),
  VALUE_B("B") {
    public String bar() {
      return "I am NOT a teapot";
    }
  };

  String value;

  public String bar() {
    return "I am a teapot";
  }

}
```

After much experimenting, I realized that `VALUE_A` works without issues, both reading from and writing to the database. I don't need the `@MappedJdbcTypes` annotation at all. `VALUE_B` on the other hand breaks everything.
I refactored the enum and moved the method out to a utility class and life is good now.